# Connecting django signal to a button click

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm trying to use a Django signal to toggle a model's boolean value to False from True when a button is clicked. I think that the Django sender would be the button click and the receiver would be the function that changes the boolean value. I'm not sure how to write out a button click as a signal sender however.

Here is my model with the Boolean value.

From models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
is_blue = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Any thoughts on a what a signal would look like that take a button click and changes this value to True?

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your model and also what you have tried. I was in the process of answering your previous question, but then you deleted it...

Comment: Sorry about that, @MeL. I deleted because I thought it was unclear. I've gone ahead and added the relevant field of my model.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do and the files you are using to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change your model field, you need to create a separate function for it in your views, e.g.:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from xxx.models import User

def ajax_change_user(request):
    is_blue= request.GET.get('is_blue', False)
    # Get your User model
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    try:
        is_blue = True
        user.save()
        return JsonResponse({"success": True})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({"success": False})
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Then you need to add a url for this view:

```
path('ajax/change_user', views.ajax_change_user, name='ajax_change_user')
```

Then in your html, you need to add a tag with the necessary class, e.g.:

```
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <a href="javascript:" class="change-user btn" data-userid="{{user.pk}}">Change</a>
```

And then finally the javascript with ajax call part:

```
<script>
    $(".change-user").on('click', function () {
      var user_id = $(this).data('userid);
      var is_blue = False # say you start with the status being false
      $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/change_user/',
        data: {
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val(),
          'is_blue': is_blue
          'user_id': user_id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data.success) {
            alert("ajax call was successful.");
            is_blue = True # if button is clicked, make 'is_blue' True
          }else{
            alert("ajax call was not successful.");
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

This is just an example to get you started, you would need to alter it to suit your needs. You could for example add an if statement before the ajax call to check if `is_blue` is true or not, so that you can toggle the value.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation. This is just what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you manage to achieve your goal!